# Clickable Text can open the Market app

Tags: android

I would like to write a text in my activity like

Buy my app

I need to make this text clickable. So once one click on it, it opens the Market app and my app shows up.

What is the appropriate view? How can I add the web link?
Would you please help (provide a small code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to achieve your goal.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle request)
{
    super.onCreate(request);
    setContentView(R.layout.market);

    Button buy = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBuyMyApp);  

    buy.setOnClickListener(this);  
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    { 

    case R.id.btnBuyMyApp:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=your package name"));
        startActivity(intent);
        break; 
    }

}
```

In xml you can use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="5dip" >
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuyMyApp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:text="Buy"
        android:textColor="#F8B334"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Write following line of code in `onClick()` method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=YourPackageName"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This will open default `AndroidMarket` application in android mobile and shows your application

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `TextView` in your `layout xml` file with the text "But my app".
Find that TextView in the android code using the `findViewById()`. Then set a `onClickListener()` on the TextView. In the `onClickListener()` use the following code

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds&hl=en")););
```

I have just used the angry birds app example, instead of that you can give the link of your own app.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

```
TextView myWebSite = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myWebSite)
myWebSite.setText("Link is:-   " + "market://details?id=your package name");
Linkify.addLinks(myWebSite , Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

And please see below link for more information.

[Android – Creating links using linkify](http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2011/01/27/android-creating-links-using-linkfy/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
      <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/click"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:text="Market"/>
```

in Activity:

```
TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.click);
        text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://play.google.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Dont forget to include **internet permission** in manifest file.